# Kubernetes "pods.metrics.k8s.io "my-pod-name" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "pods"

Tags: kubernetes, roles, service-accounts

I can't figure out whats wrong with my role binding. I keep getting this error while trying to get metrics for my pod.

`"pods.metrics.k8s.io "my-pod-name" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "pods" in API group "metrics.k8s.io" in the namespace "default""`

Here is the Cluster role yaml file

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-reader
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["", "metrics.k8s.io"] # "" indicates the core API group
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

Then I ran this command

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding pod-reader \
  --clusterrole=pod-reader  \
  --serviceaccount=default:default
```

Comment: Your `ClusterRole` name is `pod-reader` but in your command your are passing `--clusterrole` flag with name `service-reader`.  Can you check this mismatch?

Comment: thanks! i fixed that but still not working

Comment: Stuck into this same problem too. I wish this had some answers :)

Answer (score 2):

ClusterRole & ClusterRolebinding are non-namespaced resources.  So, remove the namespace line from your YAML file.

Alternatively, use Role & RoleBinding if you want to scope to a namespace.